# Bind or column index out of range SQLITE C++

Tags: c++, sqlite, bind

I have the error : **Bind or column index out of range**. The purpose of the program is to import the data from a **.mlex** file into a database. The output of the program is what I want but the error appears for each rows I want to import. 
If you have any suggestions of tips to immprove my program?
I have the same error for each bind I do,  I am not sure of the syntax of my queries.

```c
sqlite3 *db; //Declare pointer pour la db

int check(int rc);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, ""); //pour les accents 

    char *zErrMsg = 0;
    //ouvre la db;
    int rc = sqlite3_open("base.db", &db);
    if (rc)
    {
        std::cerr << "Impossible d'ouvrir la db" << sqlite3_errmsg(db);
        sqlite3_close(db);
        return 0;
    }
    //création d'un tableau
    const char *zSql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FLLL(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,Forme VARCHAR(40), Categorie VARCHAR(40), Lemme VARCHAR(40), Bloc varchar(40))";
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, zSql, NULL, NULL, &zErrMsg);
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        std::cerr << "SQL error :" << zErrMsg;
        sqlite3_close(db);
        return 0;
    }

    //ouvre le fichier
    std::ifstream monFlux("C:/Users/Quent/OneDrive/Bureau/Dico/LEFFF/lefff-3.45.mlex", std::ios::in);
    if (monFlux) std::cout << "fichier ouvert"<<std::endl;
    else {
        std::cout << "erreur, ouverture impossible";
        monFlux.close();
        return 0;
    }
    //lire ligne par ligne
    std::string ligne;
    int idx = 0;
    while (std::getline(monFlux, ligne,'\n'))
    {
        int cpt = 0;
        idx++;
        std::istringstream iss(ligne+'\t');
        std::string token;
        std::cout << ligne << std::endl;

        sqlite3_stmt *ppStmt1 = 0;
        sqlite3_stmt *ppStmt2 = 0;
        sqlite3_stmt *ppStmt3 = 0;
        sqlite3_stmt *ppStmt4 = 0;
        const char *pzTail = 0;

        const char *zSql1 = "INSERT INTO FLLL(Forme) VALUES(?)";
        const char *zSql2 = "UPDATE FLLL SET Categorie = ? WHERE ID = (?)";
        const char *zSql3 = "UPDATE FLLL SET Lemme = ? WHERE ID = (?)";
        const char *zSql4 = "UPDATE FLLL SET BLOC = ? WHERE ID = (?)";

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, zSql1, strlen(zSql1) + 1, &ppStmt1, &pzTail) != SQLITE_OK || sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, zSql2, strlen(zSql2) + 1, &ppStmt2, &pzTail) != SQLITE_OK || sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, zSql3, strlen(zSql3) + 1, &ppStmt3, &pzTail) != SQLITE_OK || sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, zSql4, strlen(zSql4) + 1, &ppStmt4, &pzTail) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            std::cerr << "db erreur :" << sqlite3_errmsg(db);
            sqlite3_close(db);
            return 0;
        }
        while (std::getline(iss, token, '\t')) 
        {
            cpt++;
            const char *c = token.c_str();
            switch (cpt)
            {
            case 1: rc = sqlite3_bind_text(ppStmt1,1,c , -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
                if (rc) check(rc);
                rc = sqlite3_bind_int(ppStmt1, 2, idx);
                if (rc) check(rc); //error is here 
                rc = sqlite3_step(ppStmt1);
                if (rc!=SQLITE_DONE) check(rc);
                rc = sqlite3_reset(ppStmt1);
                if (rc) check(rc);
                break;

            case 2: rc = sqlite3_bind_text(ppStmt2, 1, c, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
                if (rc) check(rc);
                rc = sqlite3_bind_int(ppStmt2,2, idx);
                if (rc) check(rc); //error is here 
                rc = sqlite3_step(ppStmt2);
                if (rc != SQLITE_DONE) check(rc);
                rc = sqlite3_reset(ppStmt2);
                if (rc) check(rc);
                break;

            case 3: rc = sqlite3_bind_text(ppStmt3, 1, c, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
                if (rc) check(rc);
                rc = sqlite3_bind_int(ppStmt3, 2, idx);
                if (rc) check(rc); //error is here 
                rc = sqlite3_step(ppStmt3);
                if (rc != SQLITE_DONE) check(rc);
                rc = sqlite3_reset(ppStmt3);
                if (rc) check(rc);
                break;

            case 4: rc = sqlite3_bind_text(ppStmt4, 1, c, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
                if (rc) check(rc);
                rc = sqlite3_bind_int(ppStmt4,2, idx);
                if (rc) check(rc); //error is here 
                rc = sqlite3_step(ppStmt4);
                if (rc != SQLITE_DONE) check(rc);
                rc = sqlite3_reset(ppStmt4);
                if (rc) check(rc);
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            //std::cout<<token<<std::endl;

        }
        sqlite3_finalize(ppStmt1);
        sqlite3_finalize(ppStmt2);
        sqlite3_finalize(ppStmt3);
        sqlite3_finalize(ppStmt4);
    }

    std::cout << "jai mangéà";
    getchar();
    sqlite3_close(db);
    monFlux.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `INSERT` query only inserts into one column (`Forme`), but your table has 5 columns.

Possible solutions might be to:

1. Insert the other columns with a `NULL` value *or*
2. Create your table with default values.

#### Inserting `NULL`

This means changing your `INSERT` query to encompass the other columns.

```sql
INSERT INTO FLLL(Forme, Categorie, Lemme, Bloc) VALUES (?, NULL, NULL, NULL)
```

Note the `ID` column is left out since it is automatically incremented by SQLite.

#### Creating Table with Default Values

This means changing your `CREATE` statement (and leaving the `INSERT` query alone).

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FLLL
(
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    Forme VARCHAR(40)      DEFAULT NULL,
    Categorie VARCHAR(40)  DEFAULT NULL,
    Lemme VARCHAR(40)      DEFAULT NULL,
    Bloc VARCHAR(40)       DEFAULT NULL
)
```

This is untested, but I think it should work.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I have found my mistake : the first bind I do bind nothing.But if there is anything that can improve my program feel free to say it.